# ms_active_directory - Is it possible to delete an user account?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, active-directory

I connected my Flask application with an Active Directory Server using ms_active_directory library. Is it possible to delete an user account? Something like this:

```py
import os
from ms_active_directory import ADDomain

domain = ADDomain(os.environ["domain"])
session = domain.create_session_as_user(os.environ["userAd"], os.environ["passAd"])
user = session.find_user_by_sam_name('John Liniker')
```

I would like to delete this user account. The object `session` only has methods to disable account or remove users from groups.

How can I delete this user account? Is it possible?

I was expecting something like:

```
if not session.remove_account(user):
    raise Exception(resBibliotecaPassAD["messageError"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched and discovered that there is no such implementation in the ms_active_directory library, however there is pull request #54 (implement delete for users and groups) that will include this and other new features.

When analyzing the pull request, I was able to delete the user as follows:

```
import ms_active_directory.environment.ldap.ldap_format_utils as ldap_utils

object_dn = ldap_utils.construct_object_distinguished_name(user.common_name, user.location, user.domain.domain)
result_delete = session.ldap_connection.delete(object_dn)[0]
```